# How can I remove markers with numbers 2, 5, 7?

Tags: plotting, marker

How can I remove the markers with some specific numbers, for example like 2,5,7?

```
mtps = ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][
  "ThreePointedStar", {Offset[7], 0}, {EdgeForm[Red], 
   FaceForm[None]}]; ListPlot[
 Labeled[#, #, Background -> None] & /@ Table[Prime[n], {n, 10}], 
 PlotMarkers -> {mtps}, PlotRange -> {{0, All}, {0, All}}, 
 Joined -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Most part of the code is taken from [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PolygonMarker).
EDIT: I want to remove the markers not the numbers.
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
data = Table[Prime[n], {n, 10}];    

ListPlot[
 Labeled[#, {#, # /. {2 | 5 | 7 -> None, _ -> mtps}}, {Automatic, 
     Center}, Background -> None] & /@ data, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, All}, {0, All}}, Joined -> True, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: sorry that I meant to remove the markers not the numbers.

Comment: @hana, pls try the updated version.

Comment: could you help me with my other question I asked yesterday?

Comment: assume that I don't want labels how can I make it work?
I tried this but it doesn't show anything.
```ListPlot[{#, # /. {2 | 5 | 7 -> None, _ -> mtps}} & /@ data, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, All}, {0, All}}, Joined -> True, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]```

Comment: try `ListPlot[Labeled[#, # /. {2 | 5 | 7 -> None, _ -> mtps}, Center, 
    Background -> None] & /@ data, PlotRange -> {{0, All}, {0, All}}, 
 Joined -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]`?

Comment: Thanks, it works.